# Linker error although preprocessor should prevent it

Tags: c++, xcode, function, linker, c-preprocessor

I am writing some C++ in Xcode and needed a `wait()` function. I wrote it myself and thought I made the whole thing OS cross-compatible by using the following code:

```
#if defined(_WIN32)
    void wait( float seconds )
    {
        Sleep( (int) ( seconds * 1000.0f ) );
    }
#else
    void wait( float seconds )
    {
        usleep( (int) ( seconds * 1000000.0f ) );
    }
#endif
```

The preprocessor should thus leave only one of the two functions, yet Xcode 5 gives me an "Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error" *duplicate symbol Z4waitf in*. Any idea how I could get this code to run on both Windows and UNIX without having to write two different functions?

Comment: There's already a standard `wait` function: `std::this_thread::sleep_for`. Anyway, there's no `sleep` function in Windows AFAIK, just `Sleep`.

Comment: Typo, I'll correct it. Still, my question being; why does the linker pick up a duplicate symbol error if I instructed the preprocessor to remove one of the two functions?

Comment: You shouldn't be AFAICT. Is this in an unguarded header or something? If the PP wasn't doing its job, the compiler would be complaining, not even the linker yet.

Comment: I checked, but all headers come with ``#ifndef ... #define ... #endif`` guards.

Comment: Turns out it works when moving the function definition into a *.cpp file. I can't seem to include them via the *.h file. Now I only have the declaration in the header. I'm sure it should have worked. Strange that...

Comment: Were you including the header in more than one source file? That would result in multiple definitions of the function.

Comment: If you have two different translation units including the same header file, any non-inline functions are defined once per TU, causing multiple definitions. My "unguarded header" might have been misleading, but this applies to all free, non-inline functions you put definitions for in headers.

Comment: When using the keyword ``inline`` when defining the two ``wait()`` functions in the header, then it does work! I didn't know including preprocessor guards wasn't enough. Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, you could easily fix your code by moving everything but the differing lines (Sleep line v. usleep line) outside of the #ifdef ... I would say that would be the most standard way of doing this.